# Angular - material table sorting by date not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Sorting in material table for my date column not working. I found that working with **sortingDataAccessor** can help me, and it helped for my ID column in the same table, it's working now. Where am I wrong?

.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (
      item: any,
      property: any
    ): Date | string => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'created':
          return new Date(item.createDate)
        default:
          return item[property];
      }
    };
  }
```

.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <!-- Quote NO Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Quote No.</th>
        <td
          style="font-weight: 600"
          mat-cell
          *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"
        >
          #{{ element.id }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Created Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{ "Quotes.Created" | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.versions[0].createDate | date }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: can you provide your table data, please? If you can please provide the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

`MatTableDataSource` works by matching the column name (in the `matColumnDef`) and the element/object property name.

You have `matColumnDef` as `created`, however, the element/object has `createdDate` property. So, for the sort to work it has to be same.

And the reason it works with `sortingDataAccesor` is because you are overriding the behavior of the sort by explicitly mapping `created` column name with `new Date(item.createdDate)`